# Show there is exactly one solution to $a + x = b$

Tags: real-analysis

Okay so here's what I tried:
$ a + x = b\\\implies (-a) + (a + x) = (-a) +b \\\implies (-a+a)+x=b+(-a) \\\implies 0 + x = b + (-a) \\\implies x = b+(-a)$

But I'm not sure whether this shows that the solution is unique. I've only shown that $b+(-a)$ is one solution. Maybe there is some other combination of $b$ and $a$ that'll work. But I don't know how to prove that this is the only one.

Comment: Assume there is some second solution $x_1$ such that $x \neq x_1$ and arrive at a contradiction. That's usually the way to show uniqueness.

Comment: Each of your arrows can be replaced by a double arrow.

Comment: provided that a and b are some given real/complex/whatever constants...

Comment: @Noble. So my proof doesn't show that $x$ is unique then, right? Or does it? I'm kind of confused whether my proof is sufficient or not.

Comment: Actually, given the direction your arrows are pointing, you have shown uniqueness. That is, you've shown that *if* you can find $x$ such that $a+x=b$, *then* $x=b+(-a)$. What you haven't shown is that $b+(-a)$ actually satisfies the equation (i.e., existence), but that shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: @Alraxite I'm not entirely sure, but I would show there isn't some second solution (just because it's two lines of work) but it might not really be necessary.

Comment: Do you really need  three intermediate steps to pass from $a+x=b$ to $x=b-a$?

Comment: @Micah Thank you for the reply, but why haven't I shown $b + (-a)$ satisfies the equation? I mean, I've shown that if $a+x=b$ then $x$ must be $b+(-a)$. Doesn't that imply that the expression I've given is the desired solution to the equation?

Comment: If you already know that your equation has exactly one solution, then sure. But that's exactly what you're trying to prove. For example, imagine you had proved that, if $|x|=-3$, then $x$ must be $0$. This wouldn't prove that $0$ was a solution to $|x|=-3$; it would just show that no number *other* than $0$ was a solution. But in fact $0$ isn't a solution either!

Comment: What you have shown is "if a + x = b, then x = b + (-a)." But you are not trying to prove what the solution is, you are trying to prove that there is only one answer. So what you need to show instead is that "if a + x = b, then there is only one solution for x." And as Noble stated before the best way to show uniqueness is by assuming that it is not unique. Like the proof that I have shown.

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is more than one solution to a + x = b. So let us assume that a + x = b and a + y = b, x not equal to y. Then

x = b - a

and

y = b - a.

x = y

So x must equal y which disproves our assumption. Therefore, proved by contradiction, there is only one solution to a + x = b.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you actually proved is: if $x$ satisfies $a+x=b$ then $x=b+(-a)$. 
For the other part, *verify* that it indeed satisfies $a+x=b$. Then, you're done.

Comment: I have shown that $a+x=b$ implies $x=b+(-a)$. I've understood that this shows that the solution is unique, but I'm pretty certain that this also shows that $b+(-a)$ is the solution that will satisfy the equation. I don't get the point of substituting this expression into the original equation to verify this if I've already shown that if $a+x=b$ then $x$ must be $b+(-a)$.

Comment: Well, in this case it is obvious and seen readily that $b+(-a)$ *is* a solution. But, generally, this logic requires the verification as well. I can't think of but a poor example right now: Solve $\frac x{x-1}=\frac 1{x-1}$. Then, we can conlude that if there is solution, then $x=1$. But this is not a solution now..

Comment: Sorry if it seems that I'm being too concerned about this but I want to understand when a proof is sufficient or not sufficient to a problem. I don't want to add unnecessary detail if I've already shown what needs to be. As for your example I would solve it like this: Clearly, the expression $\frac{x}{x-1}$ is undefined at $x=1$. So suppose $x\not=1$. Then we can multiply both sides by $(x-1)$ to obtain $x=1$. But $x\not=1$ by assumption, so there is no solution.